# How to save/export array as PDF in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a large cell array which I want to export as report-like format. Is it possible to export arrays (strings and numbers) as a PDF file?

For example, say I have this cell array

```
data = {'Frank' 'Diana' '06-May-2018'}
```

and I want to export the this array content to a PDF file. In this case it should simply create a PDF file with the text:

> Frank Diana 06-May-2018

Comment: Export....how? What does your data look like? What is the output supposed to look like?

Comment: Say I have this cell array data={‘Frank’ ‘Diana’ ‘06-May-2018’} and I want to exports the this array content to a pdf file. In this case it should simply create a pdf file with the text: Frank Diana 06-May-2018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know of for MATLAB to generate a PDF file is through a figure window. You can write text to a figure window, and print it to a PDF file:

```
fh = figure;
ah = axes('parent',fh,'position',[0,0,1,1],'visible','off',...
          'xlim',[0,1],'ylim',[0,40],'ydir','reverse',...
          'fontsize',14);
text(0.01,1,'text line 1','parent',ah);
text(0.01,2,'text line 2','parent',ah);
print(fh,'-dpdf','output.pdf')
```

The MATLAB File Exchange has a bunch of submissions that can help you print text to a figure window. [Search for the tag "fprintf"](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?term=tag:%22fprintf%22).

An alternative solution is to write the data to e.g. a Word document, or a Markdown or LaTeX file, and call appropriate programs from within MATLAB to convert those to PDF. The File Exchange has [a submission to control Word](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28558-control-ms-word-from-matlab). The [`pandoc`](https://pandoc.org) or [`pdflatex`](https://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/) external programs can be invoked through the `!` or `system` functions.

Comment: Hi Cris. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. However, I get the following error message: _Error using axes Incorrect input args for constructing axes object_ Is this because I want to use it in a GUI code?

Comment: Now I get this error message **Error using text
First two or three arguments must be numeric doubles.

Error in ElisaAnalyzer>Plot (line 618)
text(ah,0.01,1,'text line 1');**

Comment: @J.Birch: What version of MATLAB do you have? This works for me. Anyway, I moved the `ah` parameter to the end, see if it works for you now.

Comment: That did the trick. Now it is working. So if I want a whole cell array inside  the figure, for instance the _data_ array as described above, how do I place this inside the figure? (this is my final question for you)

Comment: @J.Birch: What is the difficulty? Do you know how to write a `for` loop? Do you know how to index into a cell array? For the example you provided, you can probably just do `char(data)` to obtain a single string, but a loop is more general.

Comment: Yes I know the for loop and indexing. I do however have the cellarray (12x30) but it creates a one-column (360x1) list of the cellarray content.

Comment: @J.Birch: Then use a double loop, so you loop over rows and columns, and write each string to where you want it on the canvas. You can adjust the canvas size to make this easier on you. The `xlim` and `ylim` properties direct where (x,y) coordinates of the text end up. And the figure size can be adjusted as necessary.

Comment: This is great. Thanks a lot Cris for all your help.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, easiest is use Matlab Notebook.  Make it as pretty as you like.

Suggest to remove matlab-guide tag from your question, doesn't belong there.

Comment: Hi Doctor Core. The reason for tagging the matlab-guide is that I’m using this code in a GUI. How can I use the Notebook from guide? I want a pushbutton to generate the report.